# Should I buffer the InputStream or the InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, buffering, java-io, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

What are the differences (if any) between the following two buffering approaches?

```
Reader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), bufferSize);
Reader r2 = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(in, bufferSize), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`r1` is more efficient. The `InputStreamReader` itself doesn't have a large buffer. The `BufferedReader` can be set to have a larger buffer than `InputStreamReader`. The `InputStreamReader` in `r2` would act as a bottleneck.

In a nut: you should read the data through a funnel, not through a bottle.

---

**Update**: here's a little benchmark program, just copy'n'paste'n'run it. You don't need to prepare files.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q3459127;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        // Init.
        int bufferSize = 10240; // 10KB.
        int fileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB.
        File file = new File("/temp.txt");

        // Create file (it's also a good JVM warmup).
        System.out.print("Creating file .. ");
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
                writer.write("0");
            }
            System.out.printf("finished, file size: %d MB.%n", file.length() / 1024 / 1024);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }

        // Read through funnel.
        System.out.print("Reading through funnel .. ");
        Reader r1 = null;        
        try {
            r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"), bufferSize);
            long st = System.nanoTime();
            for (int data; (data = r1.read()) > -1;);
            long et = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf("finished in %d ms.%n", (et - st) / 1000000);
        } finally {
            if (r1 != null) try { r1.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }

        // Read through bottle.
        System.out.print("Reading through bottle .. ");
        Reader r2 = null;        
        try {
            r2 = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), bufferSize), "UTF-8");
            long st = System.nanoTime();
            for (int data; (data = r2.read()) > -1;);
            long et = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf("finished in %d ms.%n", (et - st) / 1000000);
        } finally {
            if (r2 != null) try { r2.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }

        // Cleanup.
        if (!file.delete()) System.err.printf("Oops, failed to delete %s. Cleanup yourself.%n", file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

Results at my Latitude E5500 with a [Seagate Momentus 7200.3](http://www.seagate.com/docs/pdf/datasheet/disc/ds_momentus_7200_3.pdf) harddisk:

```
Creating file .. finished, file size: 99 MB.
Reading through funnel .. finished in 1593 ms.
Reading through bottle .. finished in 7760 ms.
```

Comment: If the underlying InputStream was a FileInputStream, would the two Readers perform differing amounts of disk reads throughout an entire read process?

Comment: I checked it using perfmon, I don't see noticeable differences. I'll update the answer soon to include a benchmark code snippet.

Comment: Big like for the package name :)

Comment: Why not buffer the disk reads as well? Without doing this doesn't the inputStream have to make read calls to the source for each byte? I don't see how BDKosher's concern about disk reads didn't prove true, seems like there should be fewer disk reads with buffered InputStream.

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputSream(inputStream), "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 5):

`r1` is also more convenient when you read line-based stream as `BufferedReader` supports `readLine` method. You don't have to read content into a char array buffer or chars one by one. However, you have to cast `r1` to `BufferedReader` or use that type explicitly for the variable.

I often use this code snippet:

```
BufferedReader br = ...
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
  //process line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In response to Ross Studtman's question in the comment above (but also relevant to the OP):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputSream(inputStream), "UTF-8"));
```

The `BufferedInputStream` is superfluous (and likely harms performance due to extraneous copying). This is because the `BufferedReader` requests characters from the `InputStreamReader` in large chunks by calling `InputStreamReader.read(char[], int, int)`, which in turn (through `StreamDecoder`) calls `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` to read a large block of bytes from the underlying `InputStream`.

You can convince yourself that this is so by running the following code:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello world!".getBytes("UTF-8")) {

    @Override
    public synchronized int read() {
        System.err.println("ByteArrayInputStream.read()");
        return super.read();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        System.err.println("ByteArrayInputStream.read(..., " + off + ", " + len + ')');
        return super.read(b, off, len);
    }

}, "UTF-8") {

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        System.err.println("InputStreamReader.read()");
        return super.read();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        System.err.println("InputStreamReader.read(..., " + offset + ", " + length + ')');
        return super.read(cbuf, offset, length);
    }

}).read(); // read one character from the BufferedReader
```

You will see the following output:

```
InputStreamReader.read(..., 0, 8192)
ByteArrayInputStream.read(..., 0, 8192)
```

This demonstrates that the `BufferedReader` requests a large chunk of characters from the `InputStreamReader`, which in turn requests a large chunk of bytes from the underlying `InputStream`.

Comment: And if you use the `BufferedInputStream` it requests data from the `InputStream` in large chunks, and supples the smaller requests of the `Readers` out of its buffer. It is not 'superfluous'.

Comment: @EJP: The `BufferedInputStream` in my example snippet (first code block in my answer) is superfluous because the `BufferedReader` requests large blocks from the `InputStreamReader`, which in turn requests large blocks from the underlying `InputStream`. The insertion of a `BufferedInputStream` between the `InputStreamReader` and the underlying `InputStream` merely adds overhead without buying any performance gain.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, if you're opening a *file* in Java 8, you can use the [Files.newBufferedReader(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-). I don't know how the performance compares to the other solutions described here, but at least it pushes the decision of what construct to buffer into the JDK.